# PHP PDO Compatibility between MySQL and PostgreSQL quoting field names

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, pdo

My source code is:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $dbname, $username, $password);
$sth = $resourceLinkID -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `ant_Action`;");
$sth -> execute();
$result = $sth -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

^ THIS IS WORKING!

```
$db = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=" . $dbname . ";user=" . $user . ";password=" . $password . ";host=" . $host);
$sth = $resourceLinkID -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `ant_Action`;");
$sth -> execute();
$result = $sth -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

^ THIS IS **NOT** WORKING due to ` problem, in PosgreSQL you must use " in this case ("ant_Action")

How to use PDO to abstract the ` or " usage based on DB DRIVER?

Comment: Why do you need to quote the table name?  It is not a reserved word.  Did you create the table like `CREATE TABLE "ant_Action"`?   Though that should simply make it case sensitive.  Did you double quote when creating?  This explains it well: http://www.dbforums.com/postgresql/1662981-must-double-quote-table-name.html

Comment: Yes I double quote it during the creation... I's a project requirement.

Comment: Maybe a workaround is to do a bindParam() with the table name itself?  Might know enough to quote it when doing the binding of the statement.

Comment: Yes it can be a good workaround, but I was searching for something that preserve a lot of queries into the pre existing code

Answer (score 1):

The backticks aren't necessary in either case: `select * from ant_Action;` will work. If you must use the back ticks, you may be out of luck.

You could use `preg_replace()` to turn the backticks in the query to double quotes, but that could be error prone.

**edited** pozs is right. Don't do that.

Comment: Nope, for compatibility reasons, postgres lowercases any non-quoted identifiers, and `ant_action` is not sure to be in that db.

Answer (score 1):

> How to use PDO to abstract the ` or " usage based on DB DRIVER?

Noways. PDO isn't capable of such things. You could use a framework (Zend framework's Zend\Db is good for it), or use an ISO SQL syntax, where you can (f.ex. name columns only with chars that work without quotation)

Comment: Does this suggest that the underscore necessitates the quoting?  Not understanding root issue here.  Ahh, seeing your other comment now.  Gotcha.

Comment: No, special characters need (like non-alphanumerical, or underscore, f.ex. "-") to be escaped, but you use uppercase letters too, which is problematical, see my comment on @Michael 's answer, or here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-syntax.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS